# Deleting a binary tree node in Python. Why self != parent.left or parent.right?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have two really similar programs which have the same purpose (remove a node as a binary tree method in a class). Only one of them work. I would love if you tell me why.

The functional program, it ends with:

```
elif parent.left == self:
     parent.left = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
            
elif parent.right == self:
     parent.right = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
```

But there's the other program which doesn't work and ends with:

```
elif parent.left == self:
     self = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
                
elif parent.right == self:
     self = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
```

So why self != parent.left or parent.right?

These are the two complete methods:

```
#It works
def remove(self, value, parent=None):
    if value < self.value:
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.remove(value, self)
            
    elif value > self.value:
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.remove(value, self)
            
    else:                                                    
        if self.left is not None and self.right is not None: 
            self.value = self.right.getMinValue()
            self.right.remove(self.value, self)
            
        elif parent is None:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.value = self.left.value
                self.right = self.left.right
                self.left = self.left.left
            elif self.right is not None:
                self.value = self.right.value
                self.left = self.right.left
                self.right = self.right.right
            else:
                pass
            
        elif parent.left == self:
            parent.left = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
            
        elif parent.right == self:
            parent.right = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
#It does not
def remove(self, value, parent=None):
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.remove(value, self)
                
        elif value > self.value:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.remove(value, self)
        
        else:
            if self.left is not None and self.right is not None:
                self.value = self.right.getMinValue()
                self.right.remove(self.value, self)
                
            elif parent is None:
                if self.left is not None:
                    self.value = self.left.value
                    self.right = self.left.right
                    self.left = self.left.left
                elif self.right is not None:
                    self.value = self.right.value
                    self.left = self.right.left
                    self.right = self.right.right
                else:
                    pass
            
            elif parent.left == self:
                self = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
                
            elif parent.right == self:
                self = self.left if self.left is not None else self.right
```

Comment: I think you copied the same example twice... They look the same to me.

Comment: I doubt very much that the second snippet is correct where it has `self = self.left if ...` because you are assigning to `self`. Surely assigning to `self` is almost *never* correct.

Comment: That's what i want to know. Why assigning to self is almost never correct?

Comment: Read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). `self` is just a name referring to the current object. Reassigning it in the context of an instance method will absolutely not do what you think.

Comment: `self` should be a reference to the instance of the class you are in, so you always want to have that to hand. (In your case, the second `remove()` method assigns to `self` at the end of the method, so in fact, it does nothing at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second snippet fails is that it doesn't change what `parent.left` or `parent.right` refer to.

The `remove()` method is all about changing the tree structure so you want to change what `parent.left` or `parent.right` refer to. Changing what `self` refers to changes nothing in the tree.

Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)